# How do I access an element inside of an array that is inside of an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Using Angular 7 and cannot find a solution to this issue. My end goal is for this process:

1. User selects their favorite kind of dessert in a drop down.
2. Then if the user picks ice cream another drop down will populate with a list of flavors.

Currently I have the the drop down with desserts in it and the user can select ice cream. I can console.log the large array which contains the array of flavors.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.desserts));
```

Will return:

{"DESSERT_ID":"1",
"DESSERT_TYPE":"ICE CREAM",
"favlorresults":[{},[{"FLAVORES":"CHOCOLATE"}]]
}

I can also console.log the array that contains the flavors:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.desserts[0].favlorresults[1]));
```

Will return:

[{"FLAVORS":"CHOCOLATE"}]

But this returns as undefined:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.desserts[0].favlorresults[1].FLAVORS));
```

I am expecting CHOCOLATE.

Drop down logic that isn't working:

```html
  <tr *ngFor="let dessert of desserts; let i = index">
    <td>
      <select (change)="dessertChange(i)" [(ngModel)]="dessert.DESSERT_TYPE">
        <option *ngFor="let desresult of desresults; let i = index" [ngValue]="desresult.DESSERT_TYPE">
        {{ desresult.DESSERT_TYPE }}</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select [(ngModel)]="dessert.FLAVOR">
        <option *ngFor="let favlorresult of dessert.favlorresults" [ngValue]="favlorresult.FLAVOR">
        {{ favlorresult.FLAVOR }}</option>
      </select>
    </td>
```

Comment: `favlorresults[1][0].FLAVORS`

Comment: I hate myself, thank you!

Comment: sometime it happens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `this.desserts[0].favlorresults[1]` is an Array (`[{"FLAVORS":"CHOCOLATE"}]`), then you need to get the element (at index 0) first.

i.e. `this.desserts[0].favlorresults[1][0].FLAVORS`

Comment: Will accept this answer when it allows. Any idea how to solve my drop down issue? (updated above)

Comment: @user68288 sorry I'm not familiar with angular. But you can post a new question. :)

Comment: @user68288 oh but you probably need to change `favlorresult.FLAVOR` to `favlorresult[0].FLAVOR` too